# Finding minimum value for each level of a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
        data
a   b
1   1   0.1
    2   0.2
    3   0.3
2   1   0.5
    2   0.6
    3   0.7
```

and I want to find the minimum value for each level of `a` ignoring the `b` level, so as an output I'm looking for something like

```
a   min
1   0.1
2   0.5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simpliest is use [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html) with parameter `level=0`:

```
print (df.data.min(level=0).reset_index(name='min'))
   a  min
0  1  0.1
1  2  0.5
```

If need output as `df` and only one column `df`:

```
print (df.min(level=0))
   data
a      
1   0.1
2   0.5
```

Or `groupby` by first level with aggregating `min`:

```
print (df.groupby(level=0).data.min().reset_index(name='min'))
   a  min
0  1  0.1
1  2  0.5
```

Comment: That worked, but I didn't need the `.data` bit, so just `df.min(level=0)`. Thanks a lot!