# pandas-Max values from Multi-index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe as shown below.

```
+-------+----+------+
|       |    | %age |
+-------+----+------+
| Group | Id |      |
| 0     | 18 | 75   |
| 0     | 30 | 12   |
| 0     | 42 | 13   |
| 1     | 18 | 12   |
| 1     | 30 | 75   |
| 1     | 42 | 13   |
| 2     | 18 | 13   |
| 2     | 30 | 12   |
| 2     | 42 | 75   |
+-------+----+------+
```

I want to get the max values from each of the group, but as opposed to many other questions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589717/finding-maximum-value-for-each-level-of-a-multi-index-dataframe), also want to show all the index-level columns.
like this:

```
+-------+----+------+
|       |    | %age |
| Group | Id |      |
| 0     | 18 | 75   |
| 1     | 30 | 75   |
| 2     | 42 | 75   |
+-------+----+------+
```

I tried this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090723/8117999)

```
df1 = df_pct.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
mask = df1.index.isin(df1.groupby(level=[0])['%age'].idxmax())
df_pct[mask]
```

But I am getting an output that displays the whole dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me working simplier solution - `reset_index` and `isin` should be omit and added `loc` for select by `MultiIndex` values:

```
df = df_pct.loc[df_pct.groupby(level=[0])['%age'].idxmax()]
print (df)
          %age
Group Id      
0     18    75
1     30    75
2     42    75
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df_pct.groupby(level=[0])['%age'].idxmax())
Group
0    (0, 18)
1    (1, 30)
2    (2, 42)
Name: %age, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

For top N with `MultiIndex` is possible use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
N = 2
df1 = (df_pct.sort_values(['Group','%age'], ascending=[True, False])
             .groupby(level=[0])['%age']
             .head(N))

print (df1)
Group  Id
0      18    75
       42    13
1      30    75
       42    13
2      42    75
       18    13
Name: %age, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response, can you also suggest, using the above solution how I can get top 3 or 5 max values of each group. Thanks in advance.